# Unity lost object reference stored in dictionary on enter play mode

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I have serializable dictionary, and I try to add unity event on normal mode, but the reference for that event is loss after entering play mode.

Basically what i try to achieve here is, I add new unity event with script in a dictionary and also list, so basically the unity event in the list are the reference from the dictionary. but once i enter play mode, the unity event are not the same instance anymore.

**ON EDIT MODE**
[image]

**ON PLAY MODE**
[image]

It took me more than 3 days of research about serializable dictionary after i decide to ask question here.

`OnBegin` is serializable dictionary that i inherit from `SerializableDictionary<int, UnityEvent>`.
`OnBeginExpose` is normal serializable list.

```
[SerializeField]
public MyDictionaryEntry OnBegin = new MyDictionaryEntry();

[SerializeField]
public List<UnityEvent> OnBeginExpose = new List<UnityEvent>();
```

This is how i try to add the unity event dynamically.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class CaptionEvent : UnityEvent{};
```

Dynamically add unity event with custom editor

```
CaptionEvent newEvent = new CaptionEvent();
eventsAuto.OnBegin.Add(i, newEvent);
eventsAuto.OnBeginExpose.Add(newEvent);
```

I heard about `Object.GetInstanceID()` that might be a solution, but i have no idea how it works. Anyone have good reference for above issues ?

Comment: I'm not sure about understanding your question, but know that when you add listener to your event in run time the Unity doesn't show it, although it is added. Maybe the problem is.

Comment: Im not adding listener/unityevent on runtime. Sorry maybe i put wrong details, i just edit the question

Comment: Its sounds like you're reigstering the listener to a reference that is override by your Awake function

Answer (score 0):

You did not wrote that you use SerializableDictionary from http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SerializableDictionary, am I right?

Show us meaningfull part of MyDictionaryEntry class because if you have

```
public class MyDictionaryEntry : SerializableDictionary<K, V> { }
```

without constructor it will not work. Your problem is specific to your code. There must be part witch clears all delegates from UnityEvent at element 1 or create new UnityEvent at place.